# Creating a board (Numpy 2D array) of 0's and 1's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Working in Python 3.7 on a Jupyter Notebook. I'm trying to create a function that returns a NumPy 2D array (a "board") of 0's and 1's. The function should have inputs of columns, rows, and the percentage of 1's I want the board to have. My professor suggests creating an array full of zeros, then looping through each one and generating a random number using random.uniform(0,1) to create the board. Or, his other suggestion, to use numpy.random.rand instead of uniform. I don't know how to use the uniform function to do this, but am completely open to it. This is what I have now:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import time
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

#I want my board to have 10 columns, 5 rows, and have 60% of values in it be 1's...
def set_board(columns=10,rows=5,people_percent=.6):

    city = np.zeros([rows,columns],dtype='int64')

#I assume this is where I'm running into my error; specifically the "city[i,j]" part:

    for i in range(columns):
        for j in range(rows):
            if rand.random() <= people_percent:
                city[i,j] = 1

    return city
```

When I run set_board(), however, I get the error "index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5".

Comment: I thought np.zeros takes a tuple? Have you tried `city = np.zeros((rows,columns),dtype='int64')`?

Comment: @Reedinationer: `[rows, columns]` also seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have swapped the row and column index. You should use

```
city[j, i] = 1
```

because the first index correspond to the row and the second index correspond to the column.

*Alternatively*, you can keep the `i` and `j` order and use

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        if rand.random() <= people_percent:
            city[i,j] = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy to create a matrix of random numbers and then converting them first to `True`/`False` with a test and then to `0`/`1`.

```
res = numpy.uint8(
          numpy.random.uniform(size=(rows, columns))
          > people_percent
      )
```

This way `numpy` will do the looping for you

Comment: `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=[rows, columns], replace=True, p=p)` would probably be more efficient. At least easier to read.

Comment: @busybear: on my system and a 1000x1000 array that is twice slower